# Initialize std::array from initializer_list

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, initializer-list, stdarray

I'm trying to initialise a member of type `::std::array<T,N>`. However it doesn't take an `initializer_list` which I pass through the argument list. This boils down to:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <array>

int main() {
  ::std::initializer_list<int> il = {4,2};
  ::std::array<int,2> a = il; 
}
```

The array refuses to initialise from it. What is the intended way to cram data from an `initializer_list` into an `std::array`?

*Note: I am compiling with C++17.*

Comment: Strongly related: [How to construct std::array object with initializer list?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6893700)

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Thanks. I couldn't find that question before.

Comment: No worries. Another signpost won't hurt in this case.